# How to left join both custom dimensions and transactions

Tags: google-bigquery, transactions, left-join, custom-dimensions

I have left joined values from custom dimensions (user id and merchants). I would also like to add transactions. Could I get some advice on how to add that into this query? Or do I have to change the structure completely? This is how I tried it out, but I get a syntax error that says it expects an end input where the FROM statement is.

```
merchants.merchant_Id,
otherMerchants.merchant_id AS otherMerchants,
merchants.market AS market,
COUNT (merchants.transactions) AS transactions,
COUNT(DISTINCT merchants.userId) users
FROM(

SELECT 
#här hämtar vi alla userIds och merchantIds
(SELECT VALUE FROM UNNEST(customDimensions) WHERE INDEX = 3) userid,
(SELECT VALUE FROM UNNEST(customDimensions) WHERE INDEX = 4) merchant_Id,
(SELECT VALUE FROM UNNEST (customDimensions) WHERE INDEX = 8) market,
hits.transaction.transactionId) as transactions

 FROM `qliro-66ee8.128389777.ga_sessions_20210628`
 UNNEST (hits) AS hits
) merchants

LEFT JOIN 

(
SELECT 
#här hämtar vi alla userIds och merchantIds igen för att kunna nyckla ihop det
(SELECT VALUE FROM UNNEST(customDimensions) WHERE INDEX = 3) userid,
(SELECT VALUE FROM UNNEST(customDimensions) WHERE INDEX = 4) merchant_id,
(SELECT VALUE FROM UNNEST (customDimensions) WHERE INDEX = 8) market,
hits.transaction.transactionId) as transactions

 FROM `qliro-66ee8.128389777.ga_sessions_20210628`
 UNNEST (hits) AS hits
) otherMerchants

#nycklar på att det är samma user samt inte samma merchant för att inte få dubbelräkning
#nycklar på att det är samma user samt inte samma merchant för att inte få dubbelräkning
ON merchants.userId = otherMerchants.userid
AND merchants.merchant_Id != otherMerchants.merchant_id
AND merchants.transactions = otherMerchants.transactions
AND merchants.market = otherMerchants.market

GROUP BY 1,2,3
```

Comment: Do you mean the `totals.transactions` GA feature?

Comment: I updated the query in my post with the query i tried, but I used hits.transactions and not totals.transaction. Might be wrong though!

Comment: Ore more question: is the `customDimensions` feature the one at session-level, or are they `hits.customDimensions`?

Comment: Really relevant question @MatteoFelici. It's session scoped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're very close! You should do something like this

```
SELECT
merchants.merchant_Id,
otherMerchants.merchant_id AS otherMerchants,
merchants.market AS market,
SUM(merchants.transactions) AS transactions,
COUNT(DISTINCT merchants.userId) users
FROM(

SELECT 
(SELECT VALUE FROM UNNEST(t1.customDimensions) WHERE INDEX = 3) userid,
(SELECT VALUE FROM UNNEST(t1.customDimensions) WHERE INDEX = 4) merchant_Id,
(SELECT VALUE FROM UNNEST (t1.customDimensions) WHERE INDEX = 8) market,
count(distinct hits.transaction.transactionId) as transactions

 FROM `qliro-66ee8.128389777.ga_sessions_20210628` t1,
 UNNEST (hits) AS hits
 GROUP BY 1,2,3
) merchants

LEFT JOIN 

(
SELECT 
#här hämtar vi alla userIds och merchantIds igen för att kunna nyckla ihop det
(SELECT VALUE FROM UNNEST(customDimensions) WHERE INDEX = 3) userid,
(SELECT VALUE FROM UNNEST(customDimensions) WHERE INDEX = 4) merchant_id,
(SELECT VALUE FROM UNNEST (customDimensions) WHERE INDEX = 8) market

 FROM `qliro-66ee8.128389777.ga_sessions_20210628`
) otherMerchants

ON merchants.userId = otherMerchants.userid
AND merchants.merchant_Id != otherMerchants.merchant_id
AND merchants.market = otherMerchants.market

GROUP BY 1,2,3
```

*Edit: missing GROUP BY statement in query*

Comment: Ah! Of course you should have to define the first custom dimension tables so it doesn't got mixed up. But I get a syntax error saying "UNNEST expression references t1.customDimensions which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [10:27] so I added a Group by within that query. Not sure how that impacts my result though

Comment: It looks like it does not give a different result - meaning no weird differences in aggregation etc. Do you know what that extra group by does and why it needs to be there? Just so I learn from what I did, haha :D

Comment: You're right, I was missing a GROUP BY in the first inner query. Since I'm using a COUNT() aggregation, I have to specify the GROUP BY for all the other dimensions (so `userId, merchant_Id, market`)